# How to change the Canvas of viewer in Autodesk-forge

Tags: canvas, autodesk-forge

In order to be harmony with my other GUI, I hope to change the color of canvas in autodesk-viewer. However, I have no idea to obtain its API or function.

Answer (score 0):

Try `viewer.setBackgroundColor` - see its documentation [here](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/reference/Viewing/Viewer3D/#setbackgroundcolor-red-green-blue-red2-green2-blue2).

```
viewer.setBackgroundColor(0, 59, 111, 255,255, 255)
```

Alternatively try the below init options:

```
const viewerOptions = {
clearColor: new THREE.Vector3(r/255.0,g/255.0,b/255.0),
clearColorBottom = new THREE.Vector3(r2/255.0,g2/255.0,b2/255.0),
...
}
new Autodesk.Viewing.Private.GuiViewer3D( divElement, viewerOptions)...
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I would like  to change the color of canvas rather than the background. By adding 'viewer.setBackgroundColor(0, 59, 111, 255,255, 255)', it can only change the background, which lays beneath of canvas.  I tried the second options---- it reminded me that  Uncaught ReferenceError: r is not defined, even though three.js was referenced.